# Add corresponding digits function

Tags: c, function

I have this `function`. The purpose of it is to take the two numbers (both `uint8_t`) passed in as arguments and to add the two 1st digits of the numbers, then add the 2nd digits of the numbers and finally `OR` the two results and return the final value.

The function as it is right now doesn't work properly:

```
  uint8_t FormatDSMode(uint8_t data,uint8_t mode)
    {
        return (((data/10)<<4)|((mode/10)<<4))|(((data%10)|(mode%10)));
    }
```

For example :

> when I pass as arguments 11 and 60 (both dec values) it gives me a result of 81
>   instead of 71. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: So you are referring to decimal digits?

Comment: I get neither 71 nor 81: http://ideone.com/2twWxN (however, note that 113 **is** 0x71...)

Comment: `(((data/10)<<4)+((mode/10)<<4))|(((data%10)+(mode%10)))`

Comment: So you want the high-nibble to be the results of your numbers-div-10 bit-or'd together, and the low-nibble to be your numbers-mod-10 similarly bit-or'd ? Odd, since your description calls for *addition*, and there is none in your sample.

Comment: Print out each of these - `(data/10)<<4`, `(mode/10)<<4`, `data%10`, `mode%10` (and the bitwise-OR of them) and check how the results are different from what you expect. The `<< 4` is suspect if you're only dealing with base-10 digits - I expect to see only mods or divides by some powers of 10.

Comment: You can't just do: `return data + mode;`?

Comment: By (sick?) intuition I divided by 16 but by 10.

Comment: Suspect this is a decimal to [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) notation

Comment: @alk Yes,i pass in the function the arguements as uint8_t decimal values.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes,im sorry ORing is what i ment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code performs an or `|` where it should add `+`:

```
uint8_t FormatDSMode(uint8_t data,uint8_t mode) {
       //(((data/10)<<4)|((mode/10)<<4))|(((data%10)|(mode%10)))
  return (((data/10)<<4)+((mode/10)<<4))|(((data%10)+(mode%10)));
}
```

Since you are doing a [BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) conversion, print your answer in hexadecimal to see the 71

```
int main() {
  printf("%X\n", FormatDSMode(11,60));
  // 71
  return 0;
}
```

---

Further: FormatDSMode() is likely an `*incorrect* BCD conversion/addition.  Need to carry if LSDigit sum > 9.  OP needs to consider what to do then if the 2nd digit > 9.  Other simplifications possible.

```
uint8_t FormatDSMode(uint8_t data,uint8_t mode) {
  uint8_t Sum = data%10 + mode%10;
  return ((data/10 + mode/10 + Sum/10) << 4)  + Sum%10;
}
```

Comment: Almost +1.  Problem is, this doesn't deal with carries, so it's not really doing BCD arithmetic.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth True that, and neither does the stated algorithm the OP seems to think they want. Without knowing the X of what appears to be an XY problem its going to be tough either way.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth "doesn't deal with carries" - saw the too.  Suspect that would be OP's next post.

Comment: @chux Thanks for replying, the output of is going to be fed into another function that expects the 71 as decimal value(so it will see 113). You were right, it outputs 113.The ORing is more correct that adding that i mentioned in my description. So won't be any broblem with carries.

Answer (score 0):

@Dukeling You were right from the begining, the problem was indeed the << 4 wich will create 
the desired number but in hexadecimal form. The function below does the job right:

```
uint8_t FormatDSMode(uint8_t data,uint8_t mode)
  {
    uint8_t digit1;     //decades digit
    uint8_t digit2;
    digit1=((data/10))|((mode/10));
    digit2=((data%10))|((mode%10));
    return (digit1*10+digit2);
  }
```